# SORT script works for owner but not editors

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I've written script to sort a google sheet by column A, and then take you to the cell next to the one you just edited, and I have it working perfectly for me the owner, but for editors, nothing seems to work starting from the "sort" function.

I assume this means some part of it is an installable trigger? but as far as I can tell I've made it all with simple triggers.

```
function onEdit(e) {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();
var NEXTcell = sheet.getActiveRange().offset(0,1);
var range = e.range;
var columnOfCellEdited = range.getColumn();
var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();


// When Column A edited
if (columnOfCellEdited === 1) {// Column 1 is Column A

//Set marker
NEXTcell.setValue('sorting');

// Sort whole sheet excluding first 2 rows by Column A.
sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows(), sheet.getMaxColumns()).activate();
spreadsheet.getActiveRange().offset(2, 0, spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumRows() - 2).sort({column: 1, ascending: true});

// Find original cell after sorting
var rowoffset = 3;
var rng = sheet.getRange(rowoffset, 2, 600);
var data = rng.getValues();
var search = "sorting";

  for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i][0] == search) {
      data[i][0] = "";
      rng.setValues(data);

      var foundcell = sheet.getRange((i+rowoffset), 2);
      foundcell.activate();

      break;
    }
  }
```

}
}

Comment: Why sort blank rows? and why activate ranges only to grab them with a second call? `sheet.getRange(3, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn()).sort(...);` Or, set 2 frozen rows (doable with script) and then sort the whole sheet of data (`sheet.getDataRange().sort(...)`)... Are there any errors that get logged (check Stackdriver logs) when editors attempt to activate your script.

Comment: Short answer. I didn't know the code, or that you could.
Since posting, I have updated the code to "Last" instead of "Max" just as you suggested. 
Also thanks for the Stackdriver advice it turns out it's protections on hidden columns stopping the sorting... I'll have to live without the protections I think.

Answer (score 0):

So Stackdriver logs for-the-win.
Turns out protections I hadn't considered are the culprit.